# PHP - Blocking File Read

Tags: php, linux, command-line-interface

I have a file that is getting added to remotely (file.txt). From SSH, I can call `tail -f file.txt` which will display the updated contents of the file. I'd like to be able to do a blocking call to this file that will return the last appended line. A pooling loop simply isn't an option. Here's what I'd like:

```
$cmd = "tail -f file.txt";
$str = exec($cmd);
```

The problem with this code is that `tail` will never return. Is there any kind of wrapper function for tail that will kill it when once it has returned content? Is there a better way to do this in a low overhead way?

Comment: The problem with `tail` is that it doesn't send a newline at the end... You never know when a line has ended until a second row is appended to the file. Also, you are aware that `tail -f` itself just loops, with a default interval of 1 sec?

Comment: Correction, the newline is there, seems to be another problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I've found is somewhat dirty:

```
<?php
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout
   2 => array("pipe", "w")   // stderr
);

$process = proc_open('tail -f -n 0 /tmp/file.txt',$descriptorspec,$pipes);
fclose($pipes[0]);
stream_set_blocking($pipes[1],1);
$read = fgets($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[2]);
//if I try to call proc_close($process); here, it fails / hangs untill a second line is
//passed to the file. Hence an inelegant kill in the next 2 line:
$status = proc_get_status($process);
exec('kill '.$status['pid']);
proc_close($process);
echo $read;
```

Comment: I think I'll need to toss this into a wrapping function, but this looks like the solution. I feel like this might be more overhead then a polling loop. But that is a question for another time.

Answer (score 0):

`tail -n 1 file.txt` will always return you the last line in the file, but I'm almost sure what you want instead is for PHP to know when file.txt has a new line, and display it, all without polling in a loop.

You will need a long running process anyway if it will check for new content, be it with a polling loop that checks for [file modification time](http://php.net/filemtime) and compares to the last modification time saved somewhere else, or any other way.

You can even have php be run via cron to do the check if you don't want it running in a php loop (probably best), or via a shell script that does the loop and calls the php file if you need sub 1-minute runs that are cron's limit.

Another idea, though I haven't tried it, would be to open the file in a non-blocking stream and then use the quite efficient [`stream_select`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-select.php) on it to have the system poll for changes.

Comment: From what I've read, it looks like `stream_select` will not block when it reads a EOF (which the file will have). Tail does exactly that I want, except it doesn't exit once the file has changed.